# Horizontal alignment in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'd like to align box1,2,3 elements in a container horizontally centered and left and right in equal distance.
My css is

```
.row_2{
   margin: auto;
   width: 75%;
   height: 300px;
   text-align: justify;
   -ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
    text-justify: distribute-all-lines;

    /* just for demo */
    min-width: 612px;
}

.box1, .box2, .box3{
    width: 30%;
    height: 250px;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
    padding: 25px;
}
.stretch {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0
}

.box1, .box3 {
    background: #ccc
}
.box2{
    background: #0ff
}
```

My HTML is

```
<div class="row_2">
      <div class="col-sm-4 box1" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 box2" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-4</div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 box3" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
    </div>
```

Now the problem is they are not centered at the page. Their left and right distances are not equal.
[image]

Comment: Please include the CSS for col-sm-4.

Comment: That's a twitter bootstrap thing.

Comment: @AMACB - That may be so, but it's still required to replicate the issue.

Comment: `position:relative;min-height:1px;padding-right:15px;padding-left:15px` and `float:left` and `width:33.33333333%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : -

```
.row_2 {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 75%;
  height: 300px; 
}

.box1, .box2, .box3 {
    width: 33.333%;
    height: 250px;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    /* padding: 25px; */ 
}
```

Adding `margin: 0 auto` to `row_2`, adjusting the width and removing the padding on `.box*` seems to solve your issue.